Why is Bochs repeatedly booting grub?
Bochs is repeatedly booting grub.
I currently have an issue with my os. Im trying debug it of course and I want to use bochs like I have before. I currently have a dualboot system with ubuntu and windows 11 just for osdev (b/c linux is better than windows for osdev). The issue is bochs repeatedly comes up with the grub menu. I can tell it is rebooting. This means it is probably a triple fault from an unknown reason. I know it's bochs because booting from the same iso with qemu works just fine (well, except for the issue im having in my os. The os issue is not causing this.). I also ran my bochs command on windows and linux. Here's the necessary commands and files that you may need to help me:
bochs.cfg:
ata0: enabled=1, ioaddr1=0x1f0, ioaddr2=0x3f0, irq=14
ata0-master: type=cdrom, path=os.iso, status=inserted
boot: cdrom

grub.cfg:
set deafult=0
set timeout=10
menuentry "SmallsOS" {
    multiboot /boot/myos.bin
}

NOTE: boot/myos.bin does exist
